# Compose Update troubles - Amazon EC2

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

Have been developing a small Laravel 5 project on my local setup. We deployed first part two weeks ago and it all worked correctly

Today we deployed some code again and did 'composer update'

Got the following error but I have no idea why and cannot seem to fix it:

Could not delete /var/www/html/backend/vendor/ircmaxell/password-compat/version-test.php: date_default_timezone_get(); It is not safe to reply on the system's timezone settings....

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you configure the timezone setting?

Comment: Do you mean on the Amazon Server or Laravel setup?....I don't recall doing it for either

Comment: The command line of PHP does have a `php.ini` file that would require setting the timezone. Run `php -i` to get the location of that file. It may not fix your problem completely, but will remove the additional problem of the unset timezone, so making the problem visible more clearly. (Unlikely case: the timezone setting is responsible for the error, but that would also be nice to know.)